# How to setup High availability in RabbitMQ with quorum queues

Tags: rabbitmq, high-availability, quorum

I am new to RabbitMQ quorum queues and was wondering how do I actually setup high-availability on a 3 node Rabbit cluster with quorum queues.

The existing HA setup works with the classic mirrored queues (ha-mode : node) but its not working fine with quorum queues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the documentation -

- https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html
- https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html#declaring

`ha-mode` does **NOT** apply to quorum queues. You should ensure that any existing HA policies are removed or adjusted so that they do not apply to the quorum queues you declare.